# How to sort index of dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a method that sorts team values in an index starting from 1 and incrementing. It looks like this:

```
def create_ranking():
    sort_one = sorted(team_scores.items(), key=itemgetter(0))
    teams_sorted = sorted(sort_one, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    for idx, (team, score) in enumerate(teams_sorted, 1):
        suffix = 'pt' if score ==1 else 'pts'
        print(f'{idx}. {team + ","} {score} {suffix}')
```

It is currently giving me this output:

```
1. Tarantulas, 6 pts
2. Lions, 5 pts
3. FC Awesome, 1 pt
4. Snakes, 1 pt
5. Grouches, 0 pts
```

Currently it is sorting the dictionary according to score value and if scores are the same, it sorts it alphabetically.

How do I sort the dictionary if I need to display teams that have the same point score on the same index value. For example:

```
1. Tarantulas, 6 pts
2. Lions, 5 pts
*3. FC Awesome, 1 pt
3. Snakes, 1 pt*
4. Grouches, 0 pts
```

Comment: Yes, the results are in the same order but teams that are tied need to have the same position on the log. See FC Awesome and Snakes. They are both tied for third place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` to collect together teams with the same score, then iterate through each group:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import itertools

sort_one = [
    ('Tarantulas', 6),
    ('Lions', 5),
    ('FC Awesome', 1),
    ('Snakes', 1),
    ('Grouches', 0),
]
teams_sorted = sorted(sort_one, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for idx, (score, group) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(teams_sorted, itemgetter(1)), 1):
    for team, ignore_score  in group:
        suffix = 'pt' if score ==1 else 'pts'
        print('{idx}. {team}, {score} {suffix}'.format(idx=idx, team=team, score=score, suffix=suffix))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be without `enumerate`?

Comment: I tried this but I am getting the following TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot that `groupby` returns (k,iterator) tuples. I updated the example to be fully runnable (but I had to change the `f` string formatting as I didn't have up to date Python at hand!)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `itertools.groupby()`, you can only increment the position-counter if the current score is not equal to the last-seen score:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
... 
>>> team_scores = {
...     'Tarantulas': 6,
...     'Lions': 5,
...     'FC Awesome': 1,
...     'Snakes': 1,
...     'Grouches': 0
... }
... 
>>> i, last = 0, -1
>>> for k, v in sorted(team_scores.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
...     if v != last:
...         i += 1
...     last = v
...     pts = 'pt' if v == 1 else 'pts'
...     print(f'{i}. {k + ","} {v} {pts}')
...     
1. Tarantulas, 6 pts
2. Lions, 5 pts
3. FC Awesome, 1 pt
3. Snakes, 1 pt
4. Grouches, 0 pts
```